# What is the name of the knife?

Tags: counter-strike

In Counter Strike: Global Offensive, we know there are a lot of knives. For example: Karambit knife, Butterfly Knife, Bayonet Knife, etc.

But what is the name of this knife from an older version of counter strike?

[image: knife]

Comment: Are you asking about the name of this type of knife? That's not really on-topic for a site about video games.

Comment: If it's not on topic I'll just remove it then....

Comment: Asking about items found in games is on topic for this site.

Comment: @Sorean Could you tell me why you think so? This is not knowledge related to video games.

Comment: [related meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11358/are-questions-about-terminology-not-limited-to-games-on-topic) and [another one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11270/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-origin-of-contents-of-the-game-in-real-life)

Comment: @Wrigglenite This is not dissimilar to asking about items in game that relate to real world call backs/outs. I'll provide you another example. "I have a screenshot from a friend's game. He said he was playing Need for Speed Porsche Unleashed. I don't know what the car is, perhaps I have not unlocked it yet since I cannot find it in my active cars. Can someone tell me what kind of car it is?" They post the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a modified **Strider "Badlands Bowie" Knife**

This is from a PDF file:

> The new Counter-Strike knife is based on Mick Strider's award winning bowie. It is an integral design that started as a 1/2" thick slab of 6AL4V titanium. The edge is press-fit Stellite, and no bonding agent was needed or used as it is held in place due to the extremely precise fit between the titanium and Stellite. The handle is fossilized mastodon ivory held in a carbon fiber pocket.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2uznsj/real_life_cs_knives/) is another source mentioning the origin of the knives, including the CS 1.6 one.